# Ionic: Change page between different tabs mantaining animation

Tags: ionic-framework, stenciljs

I'm using:

- Ionic 7
- Stencil js
- Typescript

I have a tab based app. These are my tabs in page-tabs.tsx

```
<ion-tabs>
                <ion-tab tab="tab-home" component="page-home">
                </ion-tab>
                <ion-tab tab="tab-map">
                    <ion-nav></ion-nav> 
                </ion-tab>
                <ion-tab tab="tab-refueling" component="page-refueling">
                </ion-tab>
                <ion-tab tab="tab-awards">
                    <ion-nav></ion-nav> 
                </ion-tab>
                <ion-tab tab="tab-other">
                    <ion-nav></ion-nav> 
                </ion-tab>

                <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
                    <ion-tab-button tab="tab-home">
                        <ion-icon src="/assets/icons/tab-menu/home.svg"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
                    </ion-tab-button>
                    <ion-tab-button tab="tab-map">
                        <ion-icon src="/assets/icons/tab-menu/map.svg"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-label>Mappa</ion-label>
                    </ion-tab-button>
                    <ion-tab-button>
                        {/* <ion-icon src="/assets/icons/tab-menu/refueling.svg"></ion-icon> */}
                    </ion-tab-button>
                    <ion-tab-button tab="tab-awards">
                        <ion-icon src="/assets/icons/tab-menu/award.svg"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-label>Premi</ion-label>
                    </ion-tab-button>
                    <ion-tab-button tab="tab-other">
                        <ion-icon src="/assets/icons/tab-menu/other.svg"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-label>Altro</ion-label>
                    </ion-tab-button>
                </ion-tab-bar>
            </ion-tabs>
```

and this is my routing, **app-root.tsx**

```
<ion-app>
      <ion-router useHash={false}>
        <ion-route-redirect from="/" to="/welcome" />
        <ion-route component="page-tabs">
          <ion-route url="/home" component="tab-home">
            <ion-route component="page-home"></ion-route>
          </ion-route>
          <ion-route url="/map" component="tab-map">
            <ion-route component="page-map"></ion-route>
            <ion-route url="/singlestation" component="page-station-single"></ion-route>
          </ion-route>
          <ion-route url="/refueling" component="tab-refueling">
            <ion-route component="page-refueling"></ion-route>
          </ion-route>
          <ion-route url="/awards" component="tab-awards">
            <ion-route component="page-awards"></ion-route>
            <ion-route url="/singlereward/:rewardId" component="page-single-award"></ion-route>
          </ion-route>
          <ion-route url="/other" component="tab-other">
            <ion-route component="page-other"></ion-route>
            <ion-route url="/account" component="page-account"></ion-route>
            <ion-route url="/virtualcard" component="page-virtual-card"></ion-route>
            <ion-route url="/historysupply" component="page-history-supply"></ion-route>
            <ion-route url="/historypayment" component="page-history-payment"></ion-route>
            <ion-route url="/favouritestations" component="page-favourite-stations"></ion-route>
            <ion-route url="/notifications" component="page-notifications-archive"></ion-route>
            <ion-route url="/news/:notificationId" component="page-notifications-single"></ion-route>
            <ion-route url="/faq" component="page-faq"></ion-route>
            <ion-route url="/support" component="page-support"></ion-route>
            <ion-route url="/policy" component="page-policy"></ion-route>
          </ion-route>
        </ion-route>
        <ion-route url="/welcome" component="page-welcome"></ion-route>
        <ion-route url="/login" component="page-login"></ion-route>
        <ion-route url="/signin" component="page-signin"></ion-route>
        <ion-route url="/forgotpwd" component="page-forgot-pwd"></ion-route>
        <ion-route url="/recoverypwd" component="page-recovery-pwd"></ion-route>
        <ion-route url="/onboarding" component="page-onboarding"></ion-route>
        <ion-route url="/confirmemail" component="page-confirm-email"></ion-route>
      </ion-router>
      <ion-nav /> 
    </ion-app>
```

In my page-home, which belongs to the tab /home, there is a button that should lead to a sub-tab of other, specifically /other/favouritestations.

this is the button

`<ion-button fill="clear" size="small" onClick={() => goToPage('/other/favouritestations')}>{i18n('see-all-favourites')}</ion-button>`

where goToPage use my router to push the page

```
export function goToPage(page: string){
  let router = document.querySelector('ion-router');
  router.push(page);
}
```

The problem is that if I use the goToPage function to navigate to the sub-page of a tab different from the current one, the smooth animation doesn't occur, and the page appears abruptly, which looks very unappealing.

This is the animation that I would expect.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/router

I have already tried using ion-nav-link, and the animation remains intact, but the page URL doesn't change, and the resulting page doesn't get inserted within the tab but appears as a separate page. I also attempted to use ion-router-link by passing href=/other/favouritestations, but the animation is not present.

there is a way to obtain this goal also for pages of different tabs?